# How to populate nested dictionary type object in knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this JSON object from my web server.

```
{4: {9: {'id': 9, 'name': 'key9'}, 5: {8: {'id': 8, 14: {'id': 14, 'name': 'key14'},
'name': 'key8'}, 7: {11: {'id': 11, 'name': 'key11'},13: {'id': 13, 'name': 'key13'},
'id': 7, 'name': 'key7'}, 'id': 5, 'name': 'key5'},'id': 4, 6: {'id': 6, 'name': 'key6'},      
'name': 'key4'}}
```

and I want it populate the ids and names according to its hierarchy using knockout js.

This should look like this...

- key4

  - key9
  - key5

    - key8

      - key14

and so on...
How should I use some recursive function with knockout js in order to do the above.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The ko.mapping utility will take care of this for you.

```
var rawData = <<your above data>>

var ViewModelMapping = {
    include: ['id', 'name'],
    create: function (options) { return new ViewModel(options.data); }
};

var ViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, ViewModelMapping, self);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var viewModel = new ViewModel(rawData);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('myElement'));
});
```

With the mapping, all your data will be mapped into a bunch of nested observables. It's quite nice once you get it.

If you have any control over your data source, I'd highly recommend stripping out the initial integer prepending each entry and making the objects a set of nested arrays.

Comment: Thanks! How do i apply these bindings in a to a ul in a nested format?